# Who are sales-wannabes?

Tags: meaning, epithets

I googled the word "wannabe" and found the following definitions "Someone who wants to be what they are not" and "someone who wants to be famous or successful". But how can it applied to sales? Here is some context (I guess there is a typo in the word "wannabies")

The referral code gets re-issued by 1st tier agents, and passed to a chain of sales-wannabies in a pyramid marketing fashion. The manufacturer has no way to track this activity, because redistribution occurs at each level in the sales pyramid with a new code issued by the higher tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wannabe** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wannabe)

> *n.*
> One who aspires to a role or position.
> One who imitates the behavior, customs, or dress of an admired person or group.
> A product designed to imitate the qualities or characteristics of something.
>
> *adj.*
> Wishing or aspiring to be; would-be.

According to what or who is being called a wannabe, the meaning can be inferred. Here, I believe it refers to those people who want to get better sales.